# Making a java phone book using the link list data structure?

Tags: java

I got  an assignment in which I have to make a phone book using a link list.

In this list I got to be able to add an entry. The entry must have a person first name,last name and phone number.

I have to be able to delete the first,last, and phone number of the entries.

How can I do this I am think of creating a class named entry with string for first,last,and phone number.

And when the user decides to create a new Record put a new Object entry with these fields. Into the link list.

The problem is how can I create a new Object and name it when the user want to put it on the list.

I cannot keep using the same name for an object over and over or can I?

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.  StackOverflow can help you answer specific questions, but not how to implement something from scratch. Also, a more descriptive title will get you a lot more help.

Comment: I am thinking of trying something but I have that obstacles of the Object in my path. But I will put up some code I think I have an idea of how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Suppose you have a class, `Person`, with properties as you suggested. `directory` is an object of type `LinkedList<Person>`. The correct way to do what you are trying to do is to make `Person` [*immutable*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html). Every time you want to add a `Person`, you write statements such as `directory.add(new Person("George", "Washington", "1776"))` (the constructor initializes `final String`s.

**You must make new objects because `LinkedList` only stores [references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) to objects, not copies of them.**

Really, though, you can instead of `Person` use an [associative array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), for example mapping [enum types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) for properties to strings.

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of some kind (array, ArrayList, whatever floats your boat) and store it there using `new Record(...)`.

Making a class for keeping the data is a good way to solve the problem.

Comment: So I can insert a new Entry(string name, string phone, string lastName) into each part of the array list without having to name my Object. Entry being the name of my object.

Comment: Yes, same like you can create an array of `ints` without having to name each other